# Table layout panel scroll bar

Tags: c#, user-interface, scrollbar, tablelayoutpanel

given a table layout panel with 2 columns and many rows, how can i attatch a scroll bar to it as sometimes it grows much greater than the size of the form .

Thank you

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The [`TableLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx) is an example of a [`ScrollableControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.aspx). You can therefore set it's `AutoScroll` property to True and the control will automatically create scroll bars when it's preferred size exceeds its current size. This will provide you with the desired effect with minimal hassle.

**Procedure**

1. Set the `MaximumSize` property to a preferred maximum size or you can dock the TableLayoutPanel in your form.
2. Set the `AutoScroll` property of the TableLayoutPanel to true.

**FYI:**
The Panel, ToolStrip, FlowLayoutPanel, SplitterPanel, TableLayoutPanel, TabPage and ToolStripContentPanel all inherit the `ScrollableControl` class so this answer applies to them as well.

Comment: not working until  set the AutoScrollMinSize property.

Comment: @sendreams: Can you provide details on the specific case in which you experienced this? To my best of knowledge, simply setting the `MaximumSize` and enabling `AutoScroll` as I explained above is all that's needed.

Answer (score 8):

.Net Framework WinForms `TableLayoutPanel` has a lot of bugs with `AutoScroll`.
It's better to avoid use this property. There is [better solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25601129/987850).
I hope they will be fixed in [.Net Core WinForms](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms) version.

Answer (score 3):

**For shortcut :**

```
tableLayoutPanel1.MaximumSize = new Size(tableLayoutPanel1.Width, tableLayoutPanel1.Height);
tableLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = true;
```