# Unable to enable scroll in tablelayoutpanel in C#

Tags: c#, scroll, tablelayoutpanel

I am using a tablelayout panel in my project and displaying items in it . but it is not scrollable , i have tried with autoscroll, maximum size and everything else that seems related to scrolling .

Any kind of help will be appreciated , many thanks , plz help

Comment: hello, can you please edit your code because tablelayoutpanel is a scrollable control and propertie AutoScroll setted to true works

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15620454/tablelayoutpanel-displays-vertical-scroll/25601129#25601129

Answer (score 1):

In order to auto scroll show any kind of scroll bar its parent control must be smaller than the TableLayoutPanel itself.
Check you parent size and other properties, such as *autosize, dock and autosizemode*

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're designing for that control, but it really implemente the interface IScrollable (just like this name, you could view it in object browser).

Here is mine.

```
// 
        // tableLayoutPanel1
        // 
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)));
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = true;
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.CellBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Single;
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 2;
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle());
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle());
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Name = "tableLayoutPanel1";
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 1;
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle());
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(686, 515);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 0;
        //
```

Hope this could help you, I use it just now.