# TableLayoutPanel displays vertical scroll

Tags: c#, scrollbar, tablelayoutpanel, vertical-scrolling, vertical-scroll

I have TableLayoutPanel for dynamic creation of controls with AutoScroll = true. It's work fine when I add new controls. But when I remove and all controls are visible, vertical scroll is visible. 
Some screenshots here:

Expected/correct scroll visibility:

[image]

Incorrect visibility:

[image]

Any ideas?

Update: 
Here is some code

```
tableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 0;
tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Clear();
tableLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = true;
tableLayoutPanel1.Padding = new Padding(0, 0, SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth, 0);
foreach (var item in objects)
{
     tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount++;
     tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
     tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(CreateNewItem(item));
 }

 tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount++;
 tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
 tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(CreateAddButton());

 tableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout();
```

and code for deleting

```
tableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Remove(item);
tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.RemoveAt(0);
tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount--;
tableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout();
```

AutoSize is true, AutoSizeMode is GrowAndShrink

Comment: When you remove the controls, are you removing the rows, too?

Comment: @LarsTech yes. Last row has AutoSize style, but it's look like Percent.

Comment: .Net Framework 4.8 this bug still exists

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The problem concerns [TableLayoutPanel scrolling](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/276291/tablelayoutpanel-with-autoscroll-incorrectly-shows-horizontal-scrollbar-when-only-vertical-should-show-not-compensating-for-the-vertical-scrollbars-size).
You have to use a Panel for scrolling instead of TableLayoutPanel.
Here is an example to solve this problem (for vertical scrolling) :

- Set your TableLayoutPanel properties as follow :

  - Dock = DockStyle.Top
  - AutoSize = true
  - AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink
  - AutoScroll = false.
- Put your TableLayoutPanel into a Panel with properties :

  - Dock = DockStyle.Fill
  - AutoScroll = true
  - AutoSize = false.

Comment: 7 years later and this is still a working solution.  But why is setting DockStyle.Top required (as opposed to Fill) on the TableLayoutPanel?  Without it, empirically, it doesn't work - but I don't understand the logic.

Comment: If you set DockStyle.Fill, the TableLayoutPanel will have the same dimension than its parent, so the Panel will never display the scrolling bar.

Comment: THIS is why I SO. What a golden answer in a time of need.

Comment: For horizontal scrolling, I set Dock = DockStyle.Left for my TableLayoutPanel and solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

when you remove the dynamic controls, you need to remove the extra rows that was inserted during the addition and re-size the table layout panel height to smaller than scroll container height.

During the addition the table layout panel height would have increased, which handled by the scroll container; but when you remove the controls, the table layout panel height doesn't reduce it's height to fit the scroll container.

One way to do this is to give fixed height to the rows and set the table layout panel seize set to "Auto".

Comment: Each row has AutoSize style and tableLayoutPanel.AutoSize is true

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest and funniest solution is to just disable and enable  **tableLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll**

In your Deleting procedure code  add at the end  these codes :

```
    tableLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = False
    tableLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = True
```

Answer (score 0):

I inserted tableLayoutPanel to XtraScrollableControl(Devexpress control). tableLayoutPanel.Dock set to Top and XtraScrollableControl.Dock to Fill. This solution did not solves this problem, but I got behavior that I need.

Answer (score 0):

I counted the number of rows in my TableLayoutPanel to see how many would fit. Below the amount that fit I set AutoScroll = false for the add and delete methods. The scroll will appear for large sets and disappear on small sets.

```
if (tableLayoutPanel.RowCount < 15)
{
    panel1.AutoScroll = false;
}
else
{
     panel1.AutoScroll = true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a `TableLayoutPanel` on a `UserControl`, docked in Fill mode, with all rows on the `TableLayoutPanel` set to AutoSize. This `UserControl` would then dynamically get put on a panel, again in Fill mode, to show it to the user when needed. I put the `UserControl` on `AutoScroll`, but that alone did not solve it.

In the end, I solved it by going over all controls in the `TableLayoutPanel`, storing the extremities, and baking that into a `Size` to put in my `UserControl`'s `AutoScrollMinSize`:

```
private void AdjustPanelSize(ScrollableControl panel, TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel)
{
    int maxX = 0;
    int maxY = 0;
    foreach (Control c in tableLayoutPanel.Controls)
    {
        maxX = Math.Max(maxX, c.Location.X + c.Width);
        maxY = Math.Max(maxY, c.Location.Y + c.Height);
    }
    panel.AutoScrollMinSize = new Size(maxX, maxY);
}
```

This worked, and it also has the advantage that it can be called if there would ever be controls dynamically added or removed from the `TableLayoutPanel`.