# Horizontal scroll bar not appearing in TableLayoutPanel regardless of the size of the contents in the columns

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I have a `panel` with `AutoScroll = false` and `AutoSize = false` which contains a TableLayoutPanel docked to it as `Dock = DockStyle.Fill` with the following property values:

```
ColumnCount = 2,
Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Single,
Visible = true,
AutoScroll = true,
AutoSize = false,
```

Each column contains a `panel` with `Dock = DockStyle.Fill`, which contains a `LinkLabel` with the following property values:

```
AutoSize = true,
Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right,
UseCompatibleTextRendering = true,
Size = new Size(190, 19),
Font = new Font(this.Font.Name, 14.5f, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel),
LinkBehavior = LinkBehavior.AlwaysUnderline,
Location = new Point(0, 0),
```

The text of the `LinkLabel`, which is dynamically set programmatically, can contain pretty long links which require horizontal scrolling by the `TableLayoutPanel`. Vertical scrolling, when a lot of rows are present, appears as required. Horizontal scrolling (via horizontal scroll bars), on the other hand, does not seem to appear even when there are a lot of characters in the `LinkLabel`. I have tried fiddling around with the `AutoSize` property by setting them all to false for every `Control` as, from my past experience, these can cause scroll bars to not appear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your LinkLabel is child of a Panel. If something could scroll, is this Panel. This Panel is also set to fill the TLP Cell, so it cannot autosize but just autoscroll, eventually. The TLP doesn't notice it.

Comment: What you could do is set the LinkLabel's Parent Panel to AutoSize, set all the TLP Column except the last to AutoSize, set the last as fixed width. In this case, the TLP will show the horizontal scroll bar when the fixed sized Column won't fit in. Or set all Columns to AutoSize, depending on the layout you're looking for. In this scenario, all columns will autosize to the longest string. It may be desired or not.

Answer (score -1):

Using `AutoSize = true` for `TableLayoutPanel` is not a good idea as `TableLayoutPanel` scrolling is full of bugs. It is often necessary to put the `TableLayoutPanel` in a dedicated parent `Panel`, which will do the scrolling stuff.

The solution provided here may help you : [TableLayoutPanel displays vertical scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15620454/tablelayoutpanel-displays-vertical-scroll?noredirect=1&lq=1)