# Disable TableLayoutPanel rows autoscaling

Tags: c#, winforms, autoscroll, tablelayoutpanel

I want to disable rows autoscaling of TableLayoutPanel so that it would fit, for example, 4 columns on width and 3 rows on height and autoscrolling also would work. What should I change?

Code:

```
    public UserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Clear();
        tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Clear(); 
        foreach (Picture picture in Program.gallery)
            addImage(picture);
        for (int i=0;i<tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount;i++)
            tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100f/4));
        for (int i = 0; i < 99999; i++)
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100f/3));
    }
```

TableLayoutPanel has:

```
AutoScroll=true;
AutoSize=false;
ColumnCount=4;
RowCount=3;
Dock=true;
GrowStyle=AddRows;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Percent size type is broken.
Scrollbar of TableLayoutPanel is also glitchy and is not shrink. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15620454/tablelayoutpanel-displays-vertical-scroll/25601129#25601129)

I used these properites for table:

```
AutoScroll=false;
AutoSize=true;
ColumnCount=4;
RowCount=0;
Dock=Top;
GrowStyle=AddRows;
```

and external control property:

```
AutoScroll=true;
```

Code for checking rows count and disabling unused:

```
private int cellsCount=0;
private const int rows = 3;
private int CellsCount {
        get => cellsCount;
        set { 
            cellsCount = value;
            int expectedRows = (cellsCount - 1 + tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount) / tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount;
            while (expectedRows > tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount)
            {
                tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount++;
                tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, Height/rows));
            }
            while (expectedRows < tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount) {
                tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount--;
                tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.RemoveAt(0);
            }
        }
}
```

And resize listener to set true dimensions of rows:

```
private void tableLayoutPanel1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (RowStyle row in tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles)
        row.Height = Height / rows;
}
```